# Unable to update Indices Recovery settings dynamically in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

As per [this article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/recovery.html) in elasticsearch reference. We can update the following setting dynamically for a live cluster with the cluster-update-settings.

> indices.recovery.file_chunk_size 
>   indices.recovery.translog_ops 
>   indices.recovery.translog_size

But when I try to update any of the above I am getting the following error:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "transient" : {
        "indices.recovery.file_chunk_size" : "5mb"
    }
}
```

**Response:**

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "transient setting [indices.recovery.file_chunk_size], not dynamically updateable"
```

Have they changed this and didn't updated there reference article or am I missing something? I am using **Elasticsearch 5.0.2**

Comment: It seems that there are no such settings.. Try to put non-existing setting - response will be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have been removed in [this pull request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/15235):

> - indices.recovery.file_chunk_size - now fixed to 512kb
> - indices.recovery.translog_ops - removed without replacement
> - indices.recovery.translog_size - now fixed to 512kb
> - indices.recovery.compress - file chunks are not compressed due to lucene's compression but translog operations are.

But I'm surprised it is not reflected in the documentation.